# how to see elements of vectors quickly without hardcoding

Tags: r

I have about 50 vectors named "NLTotal", "SIAuctions", "SAIC", and etc with 10 elements in each.

What I want to do is have it so I loop through all these vectors by name and look at the elements in each. I already created a 'metrics' vector which has all the names, but I don't know how to take the vector corresponding to "NLTotal" for example instead of "NLTotal".

In other words, I want a way to look at metrics[3] and not just see "NLTotal" but the vector [3, 2.3, 45, 12, 23, 98, 574, 5999, 321, 1.84].

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably get function would help you:

```
get(metrics[3])
```